# correctly using javascript to switch querystring parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm encountering the following problem.

I have to make a menu (like the booking.com left filtering menu) for my website and i'm using javascript to do that.

The problem i'm experiencing is that, in the following lines of code

```
 <ol class="select">
     <li data-value="date">Data</li>
     <li data-value="rank">Popolarit&agrave;</li>
 </ol>

var nav = $('#nav');
var selection = $('.select');
var select = selection.find('li');

select.click(function(event) {
    $(window.location).attr('href', document.location.href+"?ord=" + $(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

When i click on "date" all is ok, the url changes fine, but when i click on "rank" the url becomes first ord + second ord

I want to do like this:

I want that, if my url is url.php it becomes url.php?parameter, but if i'm into url.php?parameter and i click another li tag, the url becomes url.php?secondparameter so the first is cut and the second is replaced.

How can i do that?

Thanks a lot,

Alex

Comment: Too much jQuery! Just use `window.location = 'blah'`...

Comment: @BenM Nooo.... you can use jQuery for [everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)! ;)

Comment: @some I smell some page editing there... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the query string, why not just overwrite the query string like so:

```
window.location.search = "?ord=" + $(this).attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your document.location.href is already containing the data from the previous selection. You will have to remove the old parameters before adding the new ones.

instead of using

```
document.location.href
```

you should use

```
var old_url = document.location.href;
var url = old_url.substring(0, old_url.indexOf('?'));
```

If you then do:

```
window.location = url +"?ord=" + $(this).attr('data-value');
```

The previous ord will be stripped from the url before adding the new ord.

Comment: @BenM I was just using the code provided by OP ... but you're right, edited. Didn't know that you could leave out the first url part as in your answer though... Learning all day long :D

Answer (score 0):

Surely the following will work for you?

```
select.click(function(event) {
    window.location = '?ord='+$(this).data('value');
});
```

It might be better just to modify `window.location.search` though:

```
select.click(function(event) {
    window.location.search = '?ord='+$(this).data('value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify `document.location.search`; that only contains the query portion of the URL.